# Ip list from captured pcap python

Tags: python, ip, pcap, scapy

I'm trying to sort a previously-captured Pcap file, I want to build a list of ip source and destinations, so I can run calculation against them.

I have attempted to search the pcap file using a search function but this fails with ip addresses, any ideas?

Eventually I want the code to sniff live using the folowing code then build a list if the ip addresses.

```
newpkt = sniff(count = 100, prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("{IP:%IP.src% -> %IP.dst%\n}     {Raw:%Raw.load%\n}"))
```

Answer (score 5):

here is the result for anyone who might need it

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap("capture.cap")

test = ""
for pkt in pkts:
    temp = pkt.sprintf("%IP.src%,%IP.dst%,")
    test = test + temp

print test
```